# android java command not identified

Tags: java, android

```
ImageView counter = (ImageView) view;
```

- why we set it equal to view?
- what does this command do?

in my further code we have used it for eg.

```
counter.setTranslationByY(1500);

counter.setImageResource(R.darwable.images);
```

so what exactly this command made "counter" eligible for?
As we are performing any operation on "**counter**".

Comment: You want to read some books or tutorials on basic Java.

Answer (score 0):

So your ImageView you created "counter" was set equal to "view" so that they reference to the same ImageView object. In order words, counter would be a copy of view here.

When you use "counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.images);", what you are doing is changing the "image reference" that your ImageView points to from the one used for "view" to the image stored in your folder drawable called "images".

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Two things are happening on the first line.

1. An object cast from whatever object view is to an ImageView
2. A reference of type ImageView is created for the result

The reason for this might be that the original object that view was did not have the methods available. ImageView is a subclass of View and only. Thus the downcast was required to be able to call the methods on the subclass